# Reapply table striping after hiding rows (Twitter Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and have a striped table that can be filtered by selecting some options on a form. Javascript interprets the form inputs, and hides rows from the table that don't match the selected criteria.

However, this breaks the table striping on the table depending on which rows are hidden (gray rows next to gray rows, white rows next white rows).

I'd like to reapply the striping based on what rows are visible after filtering the results. How can I do this?

Using .remove() on the table rows is not an option, because I may need to show them again if the filter criteria changes and I'm trying to avoid using AJAX to update the table dynamically based on the filter inputs (I'd like to stick to hiding DOM elements).

**Any help is appreciated! I can clarify the question if needed :)**

Comment: Really good article about this topic that offers a number of solutions: http://christianheilmann.com/2013/12/12/zebra-tables-using-nth-child-and-hidden-rows/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely one of the annoying parts of table striping. The better part of valor here is probably just to reapply the striping with jQuery after each update:

```
$("tr:not(.hidden)").each(function (index) {
    $(this).toggleClass("stripe", !!(index & 1));
});
```

Comment: Yeah, there are solutions where you move the rows around, where you have really crazy CSS tricks, but in this case, you know when the updates are happening, so I would just do the boring thing. :)

Comment: In-case you're using Bootstrap 4, see my adapted answer below :)

Answer (score 17):

Seems like Bootstrap 4 have a different implementation. Following [@Anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/184686/anthony-mills)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24637866/6045800), this is how it would work:

```
$("tr:visible").each(function (index) {
    $(this).css("background-color", !!(index & 1)? "rgba(0,0,0,.05)" : "rgba(0,0,0,0)");
});
```

Tables are now striped by pure CSS and not by adding the "stripe" class name.

Comment: Very clean and simple. Worked perfect on my Bootstrap 4 page without any modification.

Comment: This would change header rows on pages with multiple tables, so i pasted an attempt to solve that!

Answer (score 5):

[Anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/184686/anthony-mills)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24637866/6045800) did not work for me.  First, it does not hide the Bootstrap table class `table-striped`, and second, there is not (or at least does not appear to be) a built-in class `stripe` for table rows.

Here's my approach, where I've filtered rows in a table with an id of "reports".

Here's a version to use if you define the class "stripe" for `<tr>` elements:

```
// un-stripe table, since bootstrap striping doesn't work for filtered rows
$("table#reports").removeClass("table-striped");

// now add stripes to alternating rows
$rows.each(function (index) {
  // but first remove class that may have been added by previous changes
  $(this).removeClass("stripe");
  if ( index % 2 == 0) {
    $(this).addClass("stripe");
  }
});
```

If you're too lazy to define the CSS class "stripe" then here's a quick & dirty version:

```
// un-stripe table, since bootstrap striping doesn't work for filtered rows
$("table#reports").removeClass("table-striped");

// now add stripes to alternating rows
$rows.each(function (index) {
  // but first remove color that may have been added by previous changes:
  $(this).css("background-color", "inherit");
  if ( index % 2 == 0) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#f9f9f9");
  }
});
```

Comment: The above will kill the hover class that can be applied using `.table-hover`, because the inline style takes precedence.  I'd definitely opt for using a class.

Comment: In the first block of code you're adding a second instance of class `.stripe` to every other row, as you've already added it to everything 2 lines prior.  The more efficient way of doing this, and not breaking it, is to remove that first `$(this).addClass("stripe");` before the if-statement.  That way you're just adding the class to what needs it, rather than adding it to everything then removing it from what isn't needed, which I what I believe you're trying to do.

Comment: @mikemike: whoops—that first addClass is meant to remove the class... :flushed:

Answer (score 3):

This is the same answer as [@Jacobski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6550194/jacobski)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52553884/6045800) but will keep the hover effect of a bootstrap table-hover.

```
$("tr:visible").each(function (index) {
    $(this).css("background-color", !!(index & 1) ? "rgba(0,0,0,.05)": "rgba(0,0,0,0)");
    if (!(index & 1)) {
        $(this).hover(
            function () {  //On hover over
                $(this).css("background-color", "rgba(0,0,0,.07)");
            },
            function () {  //On hover out
                $(this).css("background-color", "rgba(0,0,0,0)");
            }
        )
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

My answer build upon what [@Jacob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52553884/6045800) and [@yehuda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53308837/6045800) suggested.
This works with bootstrap4, for a table that needs both the behavior of ".table-striped" and ".table-hover".
The hover part is handled by CSS, which makes it more efficient (I noticed a small delay due to javascript handler, when testing @yehuda's snippet).

```
    // CSS
    <style>
    .table-striped tbody tr.visible-odd {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    }

    .table-striped tbody tr.visible-even {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00);
    }

    .table-hover tbody tr.visible-even:hover {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    }
    </style>

    // JS
    $("tr:visible").each( function(index, obj) {
        if (index % 2) {
            $(this).addClass('visible-odd').removeClass('visible-even');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('visible-even').removeClass('visible-odd');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this works fine with hidden rows and reapplies the striping as expected:

```
$("table#ProductTable").removeClass("table-striped");
$("table#ProductTable").addClass("table-striped");
```

Answer (score 0):

[@Jacobski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6550194/jacobski)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52553884/6045800) was great, but I had some pages with multiple tables and the header row's background would get changed on separate tables. Also my table rows that were always visible had the class "accordion-toggle" not sure if that's a bootstrap 5 thing, but that is how I targeted it! (also I don't know JavaScript so there's probably cleaner syntax to do what I did)

```
$("tr:visible").each(function (index) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("tb-header")) {
        rowIndex = 0; // need to reset the rowIndex since we are now on a new table!
    } else {
        if ($(this).hasClass("accordion-toggle")) {
            $(this).css("background-color", !!(rowIndex & 1)?  "rgba(0,0,0,0)" : "rgba(0,0,0,.05)");
            rowIndex++;
        }
    }
});
```