# bootstrap table-striped starting on opposite color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, formatting

I have two tables using table-striped. On desktop view the tables sit side by side. On mobile xs they stack as intended and I'm hiding the table header on the second table so the rows from table one flow right into table two for one long table. This is working well, except for the fact that for the rows where the tables meet, the striping is the same color and doesn't alternate. How can I start the second table's striping opposite as the first, so that the first row of the second table has white background instead of gray? I saw a somewhat similar post but the solution didn't work in my case.

UPDATE: I have tried all the jQuery based solutions from this post: [Reapply table striping after hiding rows (Twitter Bootstrap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636294/reapply-table-striping-after-hiding-rows-twitter-bootstrap) and while each has the effect of removing the table-striped class from my table, none have added the new .stripe class at all, no less as intended.

```
<!-- skills container left -->
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 xs-no-padding-lr xs-margin-three-lr skills">

    <!-- row -->
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Technology</th>
                    <th>Proficiency</th>                                                                    
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>AJAX</td><td>Intermediate</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Angular.js</td><td>Novice</td></tr>
                <tr><td>ASP.NET</td><td>Intermediate</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Bootstrap</td><td>Intermediate</td></tr>
                <tr><td>CSS</td><td>Advanced</td></tr>
                <tr><td>C#</td><td>Intermediate</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Express.js</td><td>Novice</td></tr>
                <tr><td>HTML5</td><td>Advanced</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Java</td><td>Novice</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Javascript</td><td>Intermediate</td></tr>
                <tr><td>jQuery</td><td>Intermediate</td></tr>                                                                
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
    <!-- row -->

</div>
<!-- end skills container left -->

<!-- skills container right -->
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 xs-margin-five-bottom xs-no-padding-lr xs-margin-three-lr skills">

    <!-- row -->
    <div class="row">

        <table id="skillstabletwo" class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            <thead class="skillsheadertwo">
                <tr>
                    <th>Technology</th>
                    <th>Proficiency</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ><td>MSSQL</td><td>Intermediate</td></tr>
                <tr ><td>MySQL</td><td>Intermediate</td></tr>
                <tr ><td>Node.js</td><td>Novice</td></tr>
                <tr ><td>Photoshop</td><td>Advanced</td></tr>
                <tr ><td>PHP</td><td>Intermediate</td></tr>
                <tr ><td>Python</td><td>Novice</td></tr>
                <tr ><td>ReactJS</td><td>Novice</td></tr>
                <tr ><td>Ruby</td><td>Novice</td></tr>
                <tr ><td>Ruby On Rails</td><td>Novice</td></tr>
                <tr ><td>Visual Basic</td><td>Intermediate</td></tr>
                <tr ><td>XML</td><td>Intermediate</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>          

    </div>
    <!-- end row -->

</div>
<!-- end skills container right-->
```

---

```
.skills table {
    width: 97%; margin-left:1%; 
}

.skills th {text-transform:none; font-weight:700; font-size:18px; }
.skills td {font-weight:200; font-size:16px; color: #606060; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .skills table {width:90%; margin-top:-20px;}
    .skills th, td {display:inline-block;  width:50%; }
    .skillsheadertwo {display:none;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick way to do this is to target the second table with an id selector (#) and nth-of-type selector. This way the change only applies to the second table.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .skills table {width:90%; margin-top:-20px;}
    .skills th, td {display:inline-block;  width:50%; }
    .skillsheadertwo {display:none;}

    #skillstabletwo tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd){background-color:white;}
    #skillstabletwo tbody tr:nth-of-type(even){background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.05)}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was thinking that nth-of-type might be the way to go, but the suggestions I had seen along those lines were more complicated and didn't work. This is so simple and worked like a charm. Bravo!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.